# How to add subpages in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I added a new page in the main menu, e.g. `Products`. Now I want to add a subpage e.g. `Sub Products` below a `Products` page. I tried all possible options in the dashboard but it didn't work for me. Any ideas how to handle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a quick solution for this

Go to your dash board -->Gallery -->Modules
search for Hierarchical menu  and install it
after installing then go to Configuration -->Features and enable it.
Go go to Navigation .give position like 2 for "Products" and 2.1 for "Sub products".

you will see Sub products appear under Products page.

Comment: Are you refering to the Better Menus module?

Comment: Not any more. This comes out of the box from Orchard 1.5.

Answer (score 3):

As of Orchard CMS 1.5 this is supported by the core navigation module. Now you can simply drag and drop menu items under one another in the Admin -> Navigation view. You can then control level rendering under the widget settings for the menu by setting the "Start level" and "Levels to display" properties.

See [release notes](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Orchard-1-5-Release-Notes#What%27snew?) for further details.

The [navigation documentation](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Navigation-and-menus) doesn't seem to be up to date though :(

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: http://orchard.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=242327

The module to support this (along with many other modules) is available in Orchard's module gallery.